# Put mysql results in one php array, like this?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

To get an array like this `array("123","456","789");` I use the code:

```
$Regids = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Regids))
{
    $result_array[] = "\"".$row['regid']."\"";
}
$regIDs = implode(',', $result_array);
$registrationIDs = array($regIDs); // array("123","456","789");
```

but I would expect PHP/mySQL has a simpler/faster solution for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @PetervanderWal, I need this array structure to send push messages with gcm. (from Holland Peter?)

Comment: I doubt this produces the result you want.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

try this .. use Group concat in query ...

```
$Regids = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(regid) as regids FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'"));
echo $Regids[0]['regids']; // 123,456,789
```

for getting result "123","456","789" try this

```
$Regids = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('\"',CONCAT(regid),'\"') as regids FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'"));
    echo $Regids[0]['regids']; // "123","456","789"
```

Comment: Your result is 123,456,789. I need "123","456","789"

Comment: try to use this query ...   mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("'",regid,"'")) as regids FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'"));

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your code produces the result you want.

```
// assuming the this query produces 123,456,789
$Regids = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'");
// $row contains: array("123")
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Regids))
{
    $result_array[] = "\"".$row['regid']."\"";
}
// $result_array now contains: array("\"123\"", "\"456\"", "\"798\"");
$regIDs = implode(',', $result_array);
// $regIDS now contains a single string: "\"123\",\"456\",\"798\"";
$registrationIDs = array($regIDs);
// registrationIDs now is an array containing a single string: array("\"123\",\"456\",\"798\"");
```

If you really need an array that looks like this: `array("123","456","789");` it is much simpler.

```
$Regids = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Regids))
    $registrationIDs[] = $row['regid'];
```

and that's all.

If your mysql result contains the number as an integer instead of an string you can convert it like this:

```
$Regids = mysql_query("SELECT regid FROM $tabel WHERE active = '1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Regids))
    $registrationIDs[] = strval($row['regid']);
```

Also, keep in mind that the `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated. Don't start new code with it and make plans to port your existing code to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: IMO, your solution will give me multiple arrays.

Comment: I did, when you echo $registrationIDs it gives 'array', so you have to use $registrationIDs[x] for one result. In my code the output is correct but I was wondering for a simpler/faster solution.

Comment: You should use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` for debugging, they give you the actual variable content. `echo` only gives you a textual representation which can be misleading

Comment: You are right about that, my mis-thinking answer, but still your solution does not give what I want. It gives: `Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 456 [2] => 789`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDO implementation. At first sight, it may be more difficult to understand, but once you get used to it, it reveals to be really powerful and handy (IMHO! One year ago i switched to it and i love it)!

For your example, the PDO implementation would be like this:

```
/*CONNECT TO DB, FIRST. $dbh contains a handler to the current DB connection*/
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT regid FROM table WHERE active = '1'");
$stmt->execute();
$Regids = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);
```

There are many formatting options you can specify, like

PDO::FETCH_COLUMN

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

and more...These options will allow you to get the array formatted as you prefer. As you can see i got the result in just 3 simple rows.

**EDIT**

Note: you are not escaping PHP variables before inserting them in your Query, and your code may suffer SQL INJECTION. Be careful!! Here is a [simple guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent it.
(In my code, just to be clear, i avoided the problem by just putting the table name instead of $table, just to show simply how to get the result you wanted.)